# Trying to retrieve multiple records from db and add those to JSON array. but for every loop json array is getting cleared

Tags: java, android, json

getting values and trying to add to json array

```
public JSONArray getChooseContact(Context context ,String userid,String bookid , String chapterid, String questionid ) {
            DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper(context , LektzDB.DB_NAME, null,
                LektzDB.DB_VERSION);
         SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
        JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();

            try{    
                Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                        + TB_AssessmentChooseValues.NAME + " where "
                        + TB_AssessmentChooseValues.CL_1_USER_ID + "='"+ userid +"' AND " 
                        + TB_AssessmentChooseValues.CL_2_BOOK_ID + "='"+ bookid +"' AND " 
                        + TB_AssessmentChooseValues.CL_3_CHAPTER_ID + "='" + chapterid +"' AND "
                        + TB_AssessmentChooseValues.CL_4_QUESTION_ID + "='" + questionid + "'",null);
                Log.i("logchoose", "gettingchooseSuccessful");
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
                        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();   
                        for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                            if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                                try {
                                    rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),
                                            cursor.getString(i));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
                                }
                                }
                            }
                        resultSet.put(rowObject);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    cursor.close();


            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            return resultSet;
        }
```

and trying to retrieve values as

```
JSONArray  RetrievedChoose = rdb.getChooseContact(getContext(),userid, BookId ,chapter_idchoose ,question_idchoose); 
                         finalassessment.add(String.valueOf(RetrievedChoose));
                            Log.d("logchoose", "getsuccess"+finalassessment)
```

The cursor will get two rows of output but in json array im able to get only one value at a time.. I need this operation multiple times in my project please suggest me how to set that json array is not to be replaced for every time

The result is showing two seperate values which firstone is replacing second one

Comment: yeah that was changed but no chage in output

Comment: Hint: not doing **anything** in a catch block is a really bad idea. And you know; you want us to spend our time to help you; so, please: you spend some time and make that as easy as possible; for example by proper formatting/indenting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
                JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                    if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                        try {
                            rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),
                                    cursor.getString(i));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                resultSet.put(rowObject);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Use above code and return `resultSet`